# Initializing and Destructing a 2D Vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, std, stdvector

Please I have two questions in respect to vectors in C++:

1. How to fix the problem in the following code:

   - In my header file I have:

     ```
     vector< vector< char > > vec;
     ```
   - In my (.cpp) file in the definition of the constructor I have:

     ```
     vec(20, vector<char>(25, " "));
     ```
   - The error I'm receiving is the following:

     ```
     error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'
     ```

   I know there is something wrong but I have no idea how to fix it.
2. After the end of my program, how do I properly destruct my two dimensional vector in order to free the memory?

Any suggestions, ideas or solutions to my questions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wanted single quotes `' '`:

```
vec(20, vector(25, ' '));
```

Otherwise, you're be passing a string `" "` which is causing that error.

As for your second question. You don't need to destroy it. It will automatically free itself when it falls out of scope.

EDIT:

You also need to do it together:

```
vector< vector< char > > vec(20, vector<char>(25, ' '));
```

You can't separate the declaration and the initializer like that. (at least not without an extra assignment.)

Comment: Thanks! please now i am receiving a different error:

error: no match for call to '(std::vector<std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > > >) (int, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >)'|

Comment: Oh I see! Thus if I have variables instead of (20) and (25) and i want to declare those in the constructor while my vector is a private data member of my class, then how do i deal with it in this case?

Comment: You would do it using initializer lists. (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

Comment: Crystal Clear! Thanks a lot for your time!